# hide an option based on some condition

Tags: angular

I want to hide an option from `ng-option` based on some condition. I tried using `[hidden]` attribute on `ng-option` but it didn't work.

```
<ng-select [hideSelected]="true" [loading]="isLoading" [multiple]="true"
                           [(ngModel)]="selectedIds" [closeOnSelect]="false"
                           #selectedNames="ngModel" required
                           placeholder="{{'Names' | translate}}" [clearable]="true">
                    <ng-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name.id">{{name.Label}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container) apply `*ngFor` to iterate over `names` and `*ngIf` on `ng-option` to apply the condition.

This is needed because it's not allowed to use multiple [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) (such as *ngIf, *ngFor, etc) on an element.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
    <ng-option *ngIf="someCondition"  [value]="name.id">{{name.Label}}</ng-option>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `*ngIf` in `ng-option`, and in ts file give some condition true or false,
like

```
<ng-option *ngIf="isDisplayedCondition" [value]="name.id">{{name.Label}}</ng-option>
```